# getting error while using firebase in react for using update function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

I get this error:

> Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains a function in property 'events.-MB5fWOoD9eJkz3EGdI5.at._locale.ordinal' with contents = function (number) {
> var b = number % 10,
> output = toInt(number % 100 / 10) === 1 ? 'th' : b === 1 ? 'st' : b === 2 ? 'nd' : b === 3 ? 'rd' : 'th';
> return number + output;
> }

this is form

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        if(text) {
            props.startEditEvent(props.match.params.id, {
                title: text,
                at: date,
                note: note
            });
            props.history.push("/");
         }
}}>
```

and this is async action:

```
export const editEvent = (id, changes) => ({
    type: "EDIT_EVENT",
    id,
    changes
});
export const startEditEvent = (id, changes) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return database.ref(`events/${id}`)
            .update(changes)
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(editEvent(id, changes))
            })
    }
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you are invoking this function (do not provide external links).  What exactly is `changes`?  The error messages says you're passing a function, and that's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're passing a function as part of the argument to `update()`.  This is not valid.  Look at the error message closely:

> First argument contains a function in property 'events.-MB5fWOoD9eJkz3EGdI5.at._locale.ordinal' with contents = function ...

It's saying that you have a path "events.-MB5fWOoD9eJkz3EGdI5.at._locale.ordinal" that is a function.

We can't see what your `at` property contains, but it's safe to say that you're passing some object that contains methods in it.  That's not going to work.  You'll have to figure out what you want the value of `at` to be, then figure out the specific string, number, or plain object value it should value.  What you have now for `date` just isn't going to work.

Comment: thanks for your answer, error was for at property because it was returned from moment package, so i use moment(at).valueOf()